# Contact button and input styling on mobile

Tags: css

On mobile when I click submit on the contact form the background color of the button changes to a different color to what I have set in my css. I have tried using -appearance: none; and setting the bg color as !important. At the minute my css for the button is like this:

```
button[type='submit']:active,button[type='submit']:focus,input[type='submit']:focus   
{
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none; 
background:  #f4f4f4 !important;
}
```

This doesn't seem to have any effect. Any help or pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of a lot of solutions, but it seems you all tackled them with this code.
My wild guess is that [this](http://glazkov.com/2011/01/14/what-the-heck-is-shadow-dom/) article may (or may not) help you.
Also, on what mobile browser are you currently experimenting? And have you tried other mobile devices / browsers that differ from yours?

EDIT:
[>THIS<](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/02/27/css-form-elements-problem/) might answer your question.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. I'm experimenting on windows phone and android atm.